# AleaGPU suitable for points within rectangle

Tags: c#, aleagpu

The challenge is to check if an array of points(double x, double y) is within a rectangle.

[image: See illustrative pic here].

There are mathematical formulas to get it done, and I've achieved this using CPU parallelism, but performance for thousands of points is tough, hence the reason I'm exploring the gpu route.

Thoughts? Thanks!